# Trouble with Sorting element of arrayList

Tags: java, sorting, oop, arraylist, compareto

I've been having trouble with this for a few days and cannot get past it. I have an arrayList that stores.

```
public class Application {

Time startTime = new Time(hour,minute);
Time endTime = new Time((startTime.getHour()), (startTime.getMinute() + duration));
Event e1 = new Event("Lecture", title, startTime, endTime);
```

I want to sort my events based on my endTime, the issue I'm getting is that endTime is based on startTime which uses the hour and minute from my `Time` class. When I tried using `compareTo` I was getting confused. I put it in my `Time` class, but then realized it had to be in my `Event` class to compare instances. How would I use compareTo to compare endTimes, and how do I output the sort. When I had put compareTo in my events I got

```
The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Event>)

            Collections.sort(events);

public Event(String type, String title, Time startTime, Time endTime) {
    this.type = type;
    this.title = title;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

private int minute;

public Time(int hour, int minute) {
    this.minute = hour * 60 + minute;
}
```

Also could I `extend` a class, or would I have to implement it to use `compareTo`

Answer (score 0):

> How would I use compareTo to compare endTimes,

The `compareTo` method for your `Event` class would call the `compareTo` method on your `Time` class, and use the result as part of deciding the order of events.

> and how do I output the sort.

One way would be to use a loop and `print` or `println` calls.

> When I had put compareTo in my events I got:  `"The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Event>)"`

Declare the type of `events` to be `List<Event>`.

By the way, putting `compareTo` in events did not cause that.  That was caused by another change / another mistake.

> Also could I extend a class, or would I have to implement it to use compareTo

Any class that needs to be comparable needs to "implement" the `Comparable` interface with its own type as the type parameter; e.g.

```
public class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
```

Then it needs to provide an implementation of the `compareTo` method.

Comment: How would I call the `compareTo` method on my `Time` class from my `compareTo` in `Event`?

Comment: The same way that you would call *any* method on an instance of an object!